# Como impedir a criação de registros onde um dos campos tem o valor já registrado?

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
Create Table genero_filme(
NomeF varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
genero varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
--Restrições de intregridade 
--1. Não existe gêneros diferentes com o mesmo nome
    Constraint fk_Filme_g FOREIGN Key(NomeF)
        References Filme(NomeF),
```

Como é que eu faço para eu não ter gêneros diferentes com o mesmo nome?

Answer (score 4):

Criar um UNIQUE composta por (NomeF,genero) .

```
Create Table genero_filme(
NomeF varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
genero varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
--Restrições de intregridade 
--1. Não existe gêneros diferentes com o mesmo nome
Constraint genero_unk UNIQUE (NomeF,genero) -- Nova unique key
Constraint fk_Filme_g FOREIGN Key(NomeF)
References Filme(NomeF),
--(...)
```

Se o objetivo é que a tabela **genero_filme** tenha nomes de géneros única, sugiro seguinte modelo (apenas um exemplo):

[image: Modelo de dados exemplo]

Comment: Mas se você colocar `UNIQUE` apenas no campo `genero` como vai cadastrar diferentes filmes do mesmo gênero? Não deveria ser: `UNIQUE (NomeF, genero)`?

Comment: Fiz a alteração na resposta, não entendi que 'diferentes com o mesmo nome?' se referia ao nome do filme e não ao nome do Género.

Comment: Não da correto pois eu quero poder colocar varios generos mas nao quero poder introduzir o mesmo genero

Comment: Do meu ponto de vista, a tabela género não deveria ter **Constraint fk_Filme_g FOREIGN Key(NomeF)**, e sim ser criada uma tabela de ligação **liga_filme_genero** com a `PRIMARY KEY` da tabela dos filmes e da tabela de géneros.

Comment: @user171371: o que você quer não é impedir que o mesmo par (filme, gênero) possa ser inserido em duplicata? Se você colocar `UNIQUE (NomeF, genero)` um filme poderá estar associado a diversos gêneros e um gênero poderá estar associado a diversos filmes. O que não pode ser incluído são dois pares iguais.